# Startup Error when Launching Indigo Virtual Machine for the First Time

Tags: ros, virtualbox, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run the ROS Indigo VM on VirtualBox that was given [here](http://nootrix.com/2014/09/ros-indigo-virtual-machine/) .  I used the installation instructions linked to on that page.

When I try to run the machine with VirtuialBox, a startup screen pops up where I select to run as Ubuntu.  Then a black screen appears where I wait and a bunch of (what I assume) are startup checks are described.  The checks end with [this screen](https://i.imgur.com/oqfy9Hv.png) and then the system hangs indefinitely, accepting no input from the user.  I can't figure out how to scroll up to see the previous messages.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?  I am fairly new to both Linux and VirtualBox and I'm not sure if it's an issue with my computer or how the VM is set up within VirtualBox.

I am running on a Dell L502X laptop with an intel i7 quad core and 8gb of RAM.  The VM is the 32 bit version with 1 gb of RAM and 1 (hyperthread) core allocated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204182/startup-error-when-launching-indigo-virtual-machine-for-the-first-time/) by [Guth](https://answers.ros.org/users/21766/guth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The screenshot shows a Linux kernel panic message (sort-of equivalent to a Windows BSOD). Something is wrong, and it cannot continue. A normal startup would show you the Ubuntu desktop.

You could try to see whether assigning more RAM helps (I would recommend that anyway). Otherwise I'd recommend contacting the Nootrix people about this, as this is more of a VM issue than ROS related.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0